# 'int' object is not iterable. How to solve this problem?

Tags: html, css, django-views, django-templates

1

Why does the error appear?`

How could i solve this problem?it seems to me that being a dictionary it causes me this error

```css
views
 
search(request):
    if "q" in request.GET:
        querystring = request.GET.get("q")
        if len(querystring) == 0:
            return redirect("/search/")
        posts = RelatedPost.objects.filter(text__icontains=querystring).count()
        users = User.objects.filter(username__icontains=querystring)
        context = {"posts": posts, "users": users}
        return render(request, 'registration/search.html', context)
    else:
        return render(request, 'conversation/search.html')
```

`

```html
<div class="row mt-3">
        <div class="col-4">
            <h5><strong>Posts</strong></h5>
            {% if posts %}
                {% for post in posts %}
                    <p>{{ post.text }}</p>
                {% endfor %}
            {% else %}
                <p>---</p>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
         <div class="col-4">
            <h5><strong>User</strong></h5>
            {% if users %}
                {% for user in users %}
                    <p>{{ user }}</p>
                {% endfor %}
            {% else %}
                <p>---</p>
            {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You write:

```
posts = RelatedPost.objects.filter(text__icontains=querystring).count()
```

but then `posts` is not a `QuerySet` of `Post` objects, but an integer. You should drop the `.count()` part:

```
posts = RelatedPost.objects.filter(text__icontains=querystring)
```

Comment: thank you very much for your response and availability.

my intent was to count how many times to go out in the search...so how can i do?

Comment: You can also define a variable `num_posts = posts.count()` and pass this to the context as well, but since you use `{% for post in posts %}` it means `posts` should be a collection of model objects.

Comment: thanks to your valuable contribution, I solved the problem.